# Will changes to periodic.conf file be picked-up by the system automatically?

Tags: mac-osx, mac-osx-server, tmp

I have made some changes to my /etc/defaults/periodic.conf file to change how it cleans the /tmp dir. Do I need to do anything else such as log-out or reboot to get the system (Mac OS 10.8.4) to see the changes or will the new file changes automatically be used after I save the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean /etc/defaults/periodic.conf (aka /private//etc/defaults/periodic.conf)? If so, it's read in by the periodic maintenance scripts each time they run, so the changes should take effect immediately (which actually means the next time maintenance runs, generally next morning at 3:15am).

Comment: Correct. The "periodic" system is just a bunch of scripts fired by a handful of cron jobs. The "configuration", which is really just a shell script that gets executed so that the configuration variables get set with the relevant information, is "read" every time cron fires off one of the periodic jobs.

Comment: Don't forget that you can run the periodic scripts automatically to verify your configs``sudo periodic daily`` (Or any other period)